# Encryption at database level

Tags: database, encryption

I am developing a product using Laravel. I was asked to encrypt user profile data, I was thinking of doing it using Laravel crypt/decrypt functionality, when I register users, I encrypt their data and when I want to display it, I decrypt. However it doesn't seem good for performance when I perform load test, I was looking for another solution and I came out with MySQL TDE but I couldn't find good documentation on it. Has anyone met this problem before?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind providing your crypt code? give this a try

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }

    public function getEmailAttribute($value) {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }

    public function setNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['name'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['email'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I did the same but with Trait class but logic is the same. But it doesnt perform good because I have almost 25 columns. Encrypting/Decrypting all of them could cause performance issues.

Comment: You could try encrypting the object all together but that would cause problems with reading afterwards